# wp-login redirecionando para domínio antigo

Tags: php, wordpress

Fiz a transferência do wordpress para outra pasta e o problema é que quando faço o login e clico no botão para validar, ele redireciona (logado com sucesso) para o domínio antigo. Já troquei a `baseurl` e `home` para os novos domínios mas ainda sim está redirecionando. O que pode ser ?

Comment: Experimenta adicionar estas duas linhas no wp-config: `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`

Comment: Você tem certeza que trocou da base certa? certifique-se que você está está configurando o baseurl, home  da base correta, olhando no wp-config.php, eu costumo usar o plugin Migrate DB, que substitui todas URLs para do banco para migração.

Comment: @Miguel eu já coloquei e não adiantou ;/

Comment: @FabianoCacinPinel Esse plugin migra tudo o que tiver no banco de dados do wp ?

Comment: @AlissonAcioli Ele exporta todo o banco pra você. Na exportação ele te dá a opção de substituir a URL x pela URL y, então você pode substituir a URL atual pela URL futura. Também te que configurar o .htaccess para a nova pasta.

Comment: @AlissonAcioli Você criou uma base nova para essa nova instalação? Estou achando que seu script está configurado para o banco antigo e você esta fazendo a configuração no banco novo.

Comment: @FabianoCacinPinel Eu instalei o wordpress e só joguei a pasta wp-content e wp-includes iguais para essa nova instalação, além disso também joguei o mesmo banco.. Mas consegui aqui.. O Migrate DB não funcionou corretamente no meu wp aqui, mas me deu a ideia de ir no sublime e localizar e substituir tudo o que fosse do antigo sistema para o novo e deu OK. Obrigado!

Comment: @AlissonAcioli que bom que conseguiu, talvez vc não tenha instalado o plugin certo, este é o plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/.

Comment: @FabianoCacinPinel foi ele mesmo, só que clico nas abas e ele não abre, clico em "Export" e ele não faz nada.. Mas acho que é problema desse wp do cliente que está estranho rsrs. Mas o bom é que consegui :)